# logstash for Windows Server 2012 / IIS8 access logs

Tags: iis, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm hoping to find a way to use logstash/ES/Kibana to centralize our Windows Server 2012 / IIS8 logs.

It would be great to not have to install Java on our production servers to get logstash to serve just as the shipper.  I'm wondering how other windows/IIS sysadmins using logstash have addressed this issue?

E.G., are there other, lighterweight, clients that logstash can consume?

If not, I'll probably just write one in Python that reads and posts to the logstash indexer.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you need to write program to send the logs to the logstash indexer.

For example,
Logstash indexer use [TCP plugin](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/tcp) listen at a port. You program will send the logs to the logstash indexer port. In this way you no need to install java program.

Answer (score 0):

As Bel mentioned you can use [TCP](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/tcp) or [UDP](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/udp) input plugins for your architectural need and also you can configure [redis](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/redis), [rabbitMQ](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/rabbitmq) or [ZeroMQ](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/zeromq) (well supported plugins)  and send all your logs to a queue server from where your logstash indexer will pickup all the logs and processes it. Let me know if your facing any difficulty setting up any of the above mentioned steps. I can give you an example.